# Data transformation in PowerQuery

Tags: powerquery

I have a csv source with 3 columns: Dates, Product and Sales, that I have imported in PowerQuery and need to reorganize.

| Dates | Product | Sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020 | Italy | 30000 |
| 2020 | Milano | 10000 |
| 2020 | EUR | 10000 |
| 2020 | Cotton | 3000 |
| 2020 | Synthetics | 3000 |
| 2020 | Linen | 2500 |
| 2020 | Silk | 1500 |
| 2020 | Rome | 20000 |
| 2020 | EUR | 20000 |
| 2020 | Cotton | 5000 |
| 2020 | Synthetics | 5000 |
| 2020 | Linen | 5000 |
| 2020 | Silk | 5000 |
| 2020 | Spain | 35000 |
| 2020 | Madrid | 10000 |
| 2020 | EUR | 10000 |
| 2020 | Cotton | 1000 |
| 2020 | Synthetics | 6000 |
| 2020 | Linen | 1500 |
| 2020 | Silk | 1500 |
| 2020 | Barcelona | 25000 |
| 2020 | EUR | 25000 |
| 2020 | Cotton | 10000 |
| 2020 | Synthetics | 8000 |
| 2020 | Linen | 3000 |
| 2020 | Silk | 4000 |

The problem is that Country, City, Currency and Product are all contained in the Product column, while I need to have 6 columns: Dates, Country, City, Currency, Product and Sales. My data should look like this

| Dates | Country | City | Currency | Product | Sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020 | Italy | Milano | EUR | Cotton | 3000 |
| 2020 | Italy | Milano | EUR | Synthetics | 3000 |
| 2020 | Italy | Milano | EUR | Linen | 2500 |
| 2020 | Italy | Milano | EUR | Silk | 1500 |
| 2020 | Italy | Rome | EUR | Cotton | 5000 |
| 2020 | Italy | Rome | EUR | Synthetics | 5000 |
| 2020 | Italy | Rome | EUR | Linen | 5000 |
| 2020 | Italy | Rome | EUR | Silk | 5000 |
| 2020 | Spain | Madrid | EUR | Cotton | 1000 |
| 2020 | Spain | Madrid | EUR | Synthetics | 6000 |
| 2020 | Spain | Madrid | EUR | Linen | 1500 |
| 2020 | Spain | Madrid | EUR | Silk | 1500 |
| 2020 | Spain | Barcelona | EUR | Cotton | 1000 |
| 2020 | Spain | Barcelona | EUR | Synthetics | 6000 |
| 2020 | Spain | Barcelona | EUR | Linen | 1500 |
| 2020 | Spain | Barcelona | EUR | Silk | 1500 |

In my original table, in the Product column there are 3 spaces before each Country, 6 spaces before each City, 9 spaces before each Currency and 12 spaces before each product. How can I achieve this in PowerQuery?

Comment: Sorry, the files are excel csv, not text csv, I forgot to specify that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three key steps here.

1. **Split by `"   "`.** This uses the spaces to separate into distinct columns.
2. **Fill down.** This uses the last available value from the previous rows.
3. **Filter subtotal rows.** We only want the lowest level of granularity.

Try pasting this into your Advanced Editor and walking though the steps:

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WMjIwMlDSUVJQUPAsScypBDKNDYBAKVYHWQ4IfDNzEvPygVxD7PJA4BoahFceCJzzS0ry86C24FIUXJlXkpFakplcTEChT2ZeKsgwI1M8hmXmZINchVVJUH5uKkg/AS/hlkf2kimxXsKnEOYlvIZBvIRFSXBBYiY4dLFr901MKcpMoVocGhLrYTMiPIw9goiIQ6fEouTUnPy8RGhCwBuR+IIVxV/EecyCCI/hTekQj5mAlcQCAA==", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Dates = _t, Product = _t, Sales = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Dates", Int64.Type}, {"Product", type text}, {"Sales", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Changed Type", "Product", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("   ", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"blank", "Country", "City", "Currency", "Product"}),
    #"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Split Column by Delimiter","",null,Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"Country", "City", "Currency"}),
    #"Filled Down" = Table.FillDown(#"Replaced Value",{"Country", "City", "Currency"}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Filled Down", each ([Product] <> null)),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"blank"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

Comment: Excellent, exactly what I needed. I couldn't figure using a custom 3-spaces delimiter. And also needed to replace blanks with nulls in order to fill down, but now it's perfect, thanks for that!

Comment: Please accept the answer if it resolves your question to that it is marked as such.